# Doubling string characters with recursion

Tags: python, string, recursion

Assume I have the string "my name is", how do I recursively return the string "mmyy nnaammee iiss"?

Comment: please make an attempt before asking

Comment: With map: `"".join(map(lambda x: x + x, "my name is"))`

Answer (score 2):

you could do something like

```py
def double(s):
  out = ''
  for letter in s:
    out=out+s+s
  return out
```

this has

```
INPUT:print(double("hello"))
OUTPUT:hheelllloo
```

Comment: Recursion anywhere? Shadowing `str`?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: The OP have asked for a *recursive* function. Yours is *iterative*. Also, you shadow the built-in type `str` by naming your variable which you should avoid.

Answer (score 2):

The following is simple enough. Double the first letter, and recursively call for the rest. Base case: empty string:

```
def double(s):
    if not s:
        return s
    return 2 * s[0] + double(s[1:])

double("my name is")
# 'mmyy  nnaammee  iiss'
```

Note that the repeated slicing of the recursive approach and the repeated string concatenation of the other answer make both solutions quadratic in time complexity. Algorithmically sounder (linear) would be [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join)ing a linearly built list or a generator expression:

```
def double(s):
    return "".join(2*c for c in s)
```

Comment: Thank you! I used an elif statement in mine which complicated the solution, but this was very helpful :)